# Fluent Validation is not showing the Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to use Fluent Validation. Following is the class.

using FluentValidation;

```
public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please Enter the ID");
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().Length(0,20);
    }
}
```

Employee Model looks like this

```
public class Employee
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeeController is

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostEmployee([FromBody]Employee temp)
    {
        return Ok(temp);
    }
    
}
```

I've used ConfigureServices in startup.cs like this

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddSingleton<IValidator<Employee>,EmployeeValidator>();
      services.AddControllers().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).AddFluentValidation();
      
    }
```

While checking this on Postman I'm not getting the message which I've used in EmployeeValidator. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
services.AddMvc(setup => {
  //...mvc setup...
}).AddFluentValidation();
```

to `ConfigureServices`
see more here https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Then you need check `ModelState` for validation errors

[image]

I've used next code to display errors :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Ok(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors)
                                 .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
}
```

**Also you could move validation logic to IActionFilter**

```
public class ValidationFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new ContentResult()
            {
                StatusCode = 400,
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors)
                             .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage))
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then controller will be marked with this attribute like

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter))]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
```

Comment: Yes I tried in the same manner, still its not working.

Comment: @Suchi please check my answer again

Comment: Yes but if we use if else in controller then my controller will become fatty, I don't want to use If else.

Comment: @Suchi still, to get errors you need check ModelState and get errors from here. And it is also could be read from the link i gave you above

Comment: No I want to make my controller light.

Comment: @Suchi and why ActionFilter is not an option? It is not a part of Controller. It is separate class that will handle your model validation.

Comment: Ya ActionFilter is an option but I'm practising in this way only.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, [ApiController] was missing in my controller thats why message was not coming.